# Ansible predict if entry will change before commiting it

Tags: ansible

I am wondering if for example I use lineinfile, I can actually find out if it will be changed, if yes do some action, THEN commit the actual lineinfile.

It is possible to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the use-case? I.e what is the reason to run the action before the line will be changed?

Comment: @VladimirBotka it is to backup before change occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. First-time dry-run lineinfile and notify handler. Then commit the line.

```
  tasks:

    - lineinfile:
        path: '<PATH>'
        regexp: '<REGEX>'
        line: '<REPLACE'
      check_mode: true
      notify: run handler1

    - name: Force notified handlers to run
      meta: flush_handlers

    - lineinfile:
        path: "<PATH>"
        regexp: '<REGEX>'
        line: '<REPLACE>'

  handlers:

    - name: run handler1
      debug:
        msg: Action because the line will change.
```

---

Notes

- See [Handlers: Running Operations On Change](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change).
- There is no reason to commit the line conditionally.
- The standard use-case B) is to notify the handler when something changed.
- The use-case A) makes sense only if the action depends on the unchanged file

A) This is what you want:

```
* Find out if it will be changed
* If yes ---> do some action
* Commit the actual lineinfile
```

B) This is what Ansible usually offers:

```
* Commit the actual lineinfile
* Find out if it was changed
* If yes ---> do some action
```

Comment: Nice it worked !

But now I am wondering if it there's a way to avoid task duplication (having 2x lineinfile call, with basically the same parameters).

Comment: I don't know how this might be accomplished. The philosophy and goal of Ansible are to define the state of the system and make the procedure idempotent. Nobody cares that much what was the state of the system "before". When a procedure is idempotent it is not a big problem to run it twice.

Comment: @dctremblay  You can use the attribute 'backup' to avoid duplication. I showed an example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) can take the attribute `backup` which will:

> Create a backup file including the timestamp information so you can
>   get the original file back if you somehow clobbered it incorrectly.

For instance:

```
tasks:
- lineinfile:
    path: ...
    regexp: ...
    line: ...
    backup: yes
```